# Is it possible to check with Twig the role the current user has?

Tags: 9, group

Is it possible to check with Twig the Group role the current user has, to use it as in the following code?

```
{% if is_member == true %}
  {# … #}
{% endif %}
```

I tried with `$group_memberships = \Drupal::service('group.membership_loader').loadByUser($account);` in the .theme file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you wrote already code, we would like to see more than a single line. It could be the code you wrote is the one to use, but it contains a typo.

Comment: Welcome. 
could you please clarify in which twig template you want to do it?
page? node? block?

Answer (score 4):

to see the list of user roles try the following:

```
{% set roles = user.getroles() %}
{{ dump(roles) }}
```

if you want an specific role try

If you want to do anything only for the particular role then do this:

```
{% if 'ROLE_MACHINE_NAME' in user.getroles()  %}
  // do your stuffs here
{% endif %}
```